# Setting margins properly with css2pdf@cloudformatter xeponline

Tags: pdf-generation

This formatter is great for converting html to PDFs however the margin options don't seem to work properly. If I keep all the values the same like this...

```
<a href="#" onclick="return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('nutrition-plan',
        {
            pageWidth:'216mm', 
            pageHeight:'279mm',  
            pageMarginTop: '10mm',
            pageMarginRight: '10mm',
            pageMarginBottom: '10mm',
            pageMarginLeft: '10mm', 
            filename:'<?php the_title(); ?>'
                                 });" class="download"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download PDF</a>
```

then I get the desired 10mm around the page, however if I change any of the values, it seems to break and I get no margin at all. I really want a bigger margin at the top than at the bottom. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try using style to set page margin:

```
<div id="nutrition-plan" style="padding: 100px 10px 50px 10px;">
```